# C code and right syntax for a condition

Tags: c, if-statement

I have C code where I declare some variables: `char c[8][8];  int pos[2][2];` (k and l are integers) and I put some condition as:

```
if('a' <= c[pos[k][l]][pos[k][l+1]]<='z'){...}else{...}
```

where the condition verifies that the character `c[pos[k][l]][pos[k][l+1]]` is some letter between 'a' and 'z'. But I get invariably the same error message

```
line ..: warning: comparisons like 'X<=Y<=Z' do not have their mathematical meaning
```

The question is for sure very simple but what is the right syntax to compare inside an if-statement?

Comment: That array indexing expression makes my brain's parser cry.

Comment: Holy cow, I love how all 5 answers are basically identical and at more or less the same time.

Comment: The error message should at least have told you that the fact that you were doing this with array elements had nothing to do with it.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17095324/16217248)

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is that C parses

```
a <= b <= c
```

as

```
(a <= b) <= c
```

Meaning "check if a ≤ b.  Then, take the result of that comparison (0 or 1) and check if it is less than `c`.  This is not at all the same thing as checking whether a ≤ b ≤ c, and the compiler error is trying to warn you that what you have written and the mathematical expression you probably intended are not the same thing.

To fix this, as others have mentioned, split the condition into two checks, then AND them together.  In the general case, this would be rewritten as

```
if (a <= b && b <= c) {
    ...
}
```

In your case, you would write

```
if ('a' <= c[pos[k][l]][pos[k][l+1]] && c[pos[k][l]][pos[k][l+1]] <= 'z') {
   ...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use logical *AND* operator `&&` and split the condition into two parts:

```
if('a' <= c[pos[k][l]][pos[k][l+1]] && c[pos[k][l]][pos[k][l+1]] <='z')
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to split it up into a boolean expression using `&&`, the **AND** operator:

```
if (('a' <= c[pos[k][l]][pos[k][l+1]]) &&
    (c[pos[k][l]][pos[k][l+1]] <= 'z'))
```

Better yet:

```
char ch;

... 

ch = c[pos[k][l]][pos[k][l+1]];
if (('a' <= ch) && (ch <= 'z'))
    ...
```

Comment: You meant `if (('a' <= ch) && (ch <= 'z'))`, I hope.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two comparison and Boolean logic.

Something like:

```
 if('a' <= c[pos[k][l]][pos[k][l+1]] && c[pos[k][l]][pos[k][l+1]] <='z'){...}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use logical operators like AND (`&&`) Try some thing like:

```
if(('a' <= c[pos[k][l]][pos[k][l+1]])&&(c[pos[k][l]][pos[k][l+1]] <= 'z'))
```